# SSH batch remove characters from filename

Tags: ssh, debian, putty

I have a folder with thousands of files and I need to rename only some of those files and remove a set of characters. Can anyone tell me which command to use from shell (putty)?
I have something like:

```
image01-GB.jpg
image02-GB.jpg
image03.jpg
image04GB.jpg
image05.jpg
image06GB.jpg
```

I need to remove `-GB` and `GB` if those characters exist, everything else should stay as is. I've been googling for the past 2 hours and can't find anything useful. Can anyone shed some light, please? BTW, I'm a total noob when it comes to shell.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for the [rename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) command.

Comment: possibly, but I'm not sure how to use it. I didn't put the exact file names because I didn't think it was important, but my images aren't named in any specific pattern. I don't really have image01, image02 etc. I have something like house-BG.jpg, city.jpg, grassBG.jpg, graceful-BG.jpg etc.